# How to handle database disconnects while using mysql jobstore with Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, apscheduler

I am using Flask Sqlalchemy and have given mysql as job store while initiating the Scheduler. But Sometimes when I add job to scheduler it throws 'Mysql Server has gone away' error probably client has disconnected..Can anyone suggest if we can handle this using some event listeners and reconnect to the database..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL closes it self the stale connections (8 hours of inactivity by default). You can set the `pool recycle` to solve this problem.

`app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 300`

[more info](http://douglatornell.ca/blog/2012/01/08/staying-alive/).

Comment: Does SQLAlchemy close stale connections? Or does MySQL close stale connections?

Comment: MySQL, you use `SQLALCHEMY_POOR_RECYCLE` to fix it.

Comment: In current versions of SQLAlchemy the pool recycle units are seconds, so `300` is only 5 minutes. You might want to use something like `3600` (an hour) instead?